# Project Euler Number 338

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I'm stuck on Project Euler [problem 338](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=338). Here is what I've done so far...

Let's denote a rectangle with width and height `x` and `y` respectively `(x,y)`. To form new rectangles you can consider cutting a kind of stairway down the diagonal (as is shown in in the problem description) with d steps. But to form a new rectangle the following must hold: `d|x` and either `(d-1)|y` or `(d+1)|y`. The new rectangle then becomes either `(x/d*(d-1), y/(d-1)*d)` or `(x/d*(d+1), y/(d+1)*d)`. Obviously the new rectangles area is the same as the old rectangle's.

That was enough to confirm that `G(10)=55` and `G(1000)=971745` by looping through all relevant d and adding all new rectangles to a set being careful to count `(x,y)` and `(y,x)` only once.

The main issue with this method is that it's possible to make a new rectangle in two different ways. For example, `(9,8)` can transform into both `(6,12)` and `(12,6)` with `d=3` and either `d-1` or `d+1` dividing `y`. Or another example of `(4,4)` transforms into both `(2,8)` and `(8,2)` with `d=2` and `d=1` respectively.

I was then lucky enough to read [this blog post](https://jaroslawpawlak.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/problem-338-4/). It removes the need to check for duplicates by searching for one of the sides instead.

```
def F(w, h):
    if w&1 and h&1: return 0
    if w<h: w,h = h,w

    r = 0
    x = 1
    while x**2 <= w*h:
        if (w*h)%x!=0 or x==h:
            x += 1
            continue

        if w%(w-x)==0 or x%(x-h)==0:
            r += 1

        x += 1

    return r

def G(N):
    s = 0
    for w in range(1, N+1):
        for h in range(1, w+1):
            s += F(w,h)

    return s
```

G(10<sup>12</sup>) would require far too long to solve regardless of how fast F is though. I think it's necessary to either use some kind of sieving algorithm where we loop through all x < 10<sup>12</sup> counting how many (w,h) satisfy h <= w <= 10<sup>12</sup>, x|(w*h), x != h and (w-x)|w or (x-h)|x.

I think an O(n<sup>2/3</sup>) algorithm must be possible... but I'm stuck here!

---

**Edit**: I don't have access to the forum since I am unable to solve it. That's why I'm asking for help. I have completed most other questions and want to tackle *this* question now!

**Edit 2**: I think considering the areas by prime factors is a dead end. That's because there are 10<sup>24</sup> different areas. Rectangles with prime areas have 0 solutions, rectangles with semiprime areas have 1 solution if one of the primes is 2 otherwise they have 0 solutions. But counting all the semiprime solutions alone would take too long since we'd need to count all the primes p such that 2*p < 10<sup>24</sup> which is not feasible.

**Edit 3**: I've stripped down the code:

```
def G(N):
    s = 0
    for x in range(1, N):
        for h in range(1, N+1):
            if x==h: continue
            for w in range(max(h, x**2//h), N+1):
                if (w*h)%x==0 and x%(w-x)==0 and x%(x-h)==0:
                    s -= 1

    for x in range(1, N):
        for h in range(1, N+1):
            if x==h: continue
            for w in range(max(h, x**2//h), N+1):
                if (w*h)%x==0 and w%(w-x)==0:
                    s += 1

    for x in range(1, N):
        for h in range(1, N+1):
            if x==h: continue
            for w in range(max(h, x**2//h), N+1):
                if (w*h)%x==0 and h%(x-h)==0:
                    s += 1

    return s
```

I don't think breaking the brute-force code down will work though. Remember it's enough that we just count the solutions (x, w, h) to each of these three subproblems. The last such summation would have the constraints 0 < x < N, 0 < h < N+1, x!=h, max(h, x<sup>2</sup>/h) < w < N+1, x|wh and x-h|h.

I think we should start with the assumption that some prime p divides x, w, h or even x-h and then see what we can deduce about the other variables. If that works well, maybe consider p<sup>k</sup> for arbitrary k.

Comment: Another way to think about this is in terms of prime factors of the of the numbers so with the 9 * 4 example you have 3*3 and 2*2 which can of course arranged in three other unique ways, 3 and 3*2*2, 2 and 3*3*2, 3*2 and 3*2. Is it quicker to count unique permutaions? I've no idea if this approach works but it's another way to attack the problem. Good Luck.

Comment: have you printed out G(0)...G(10) or so and searched for the sequence in http://oeis.org/ ?

Comment: also, does it simplify things (particularly your worrying about duplicates) to separate the examples on that page into 2: the top two are "horizontal slides"; the bottom one is a "vertical slide".  that's just you're d+/-1, except that you can view the vertical as a rotated horizontal.  so you only count horizontals, but include both rotations for non-square forms.  maybe it's irrelevant but it might simplify the bookeeping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution yet, but something interesting for Python. I realized that Python can be used as a convenient tool for notation of algorithms! Basically I wrote down a program similar to yours and started transforming the program logically which leave the results unchanged. I came up with

```
def order(x,y):
    if x>=y:
        return (x,y)
    else:
        return (y,x)

N=1000
num=set()
for n in range(1, N+1):
    for a in range(1,N//n+1):
        for b in range(1,N//(n+1)+1):
            if a==b: continue
            num.add((order(a*n,b*(n+1)), order(b*n,a*(n+1))))

print(N, len(num))
```

Obviously brute force or even a simple loop over 10^12 is not feasible, but maybe with this algorithm one can find a closed form expression at some point. If it wasn't for the set character of num, it would be doable. Maybe one can find duplicate point this way.

This could be a dead end, but still it's pretty cool that Python can be used for notation and work with algorithms :)

Any progress on your side?